# Create sublist from list with non continuous indices

Tags: java, android

In Java, I would like to use the `clear()` method on a list so that the items cleared from the sublist are also removed from the original list.  Is there a way to create a sublist where the indices are non continuous, so that I can still use the `clear()` method to remove the items from the original list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the default `List` implementations support this behavior.  You could override `ArrayList` and support a `clear()`, `remove()`, etc.. that turns around and calls `remove()` on the parent list.

Something like the following example code.  But to keep it properly in sync with the parent is going to *take a lot of work*.  If you can limit the number of calls that you need to support then it would be a lot easier of course.

```
public class SubArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    public SubArrayList(List<T> parentList, int start, int end) {
        ...;
    }

    @Override
    public T remove(int index) {
        T removed = super.remove(index);
        // should not remove by position because position in parent might change
        parentList.remove(removed);
        return removed;
    }

    @Override
    public T remove(Object obj) {
        if (super.remove(obj)) {
            parentList.remove(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Calling `clear()` on the sublist removes the elements from the original list, but also updates indices.

If you want to retain the indices, instead of using `.clear()` you can use `.set(i, null)` - this will retain "empty slots" in the list. You'll just need to be careful when iterating. Another thing you can do is use a `Map<Integer, Foo>` where `Integer` is your index. That way you will be in charge of managing the indices.

Update: if you want to remove particular elements, rather than a sublist, simply call `.remove(index)`

Comment: Don't some implementations of `List` not allow null elements? So `set(i, null)` would throw an exception

Comment: ArrayList and LinkedList allow nulls. Some other implementations can of course throw an exception, but that's not the rule

Comment: @Bozho, i don't mind if the indices are updated.  what i'm trying to do is, for example, take the first and third element of the list and create a sublist with it, for which i can use clear() on.  for the sublist() method , it only let's you define a range. any ideas? maybe i'm not understanding your answer

Comment: yes, it's a range. But if you want to remove individual elements, then do so with `.remove(i)` (see updated)

Comment: @bohzho, is there anyway to generate a sublist first from the indices? the reason i would like this is i want to hold onto the sublist for other operations before deleting. thx!

Comment: Simply have another list of indices